# Imagem no Crystal Reports

Tags: javascript, c#, crystal-reports

Estou usando Crystal Reports em meu projeto Asp.Net MVC.

Em Database Fields no Crystal Reports em meu Visual Studio, conectei uma classe do C# ao invés de ir ao Banco de Dados.

Esta é a classe:

```
public class MinhaImagem
    {
        public byte[] Imagem{ get; set; }
    }
```

O objetivo é obter um canvas no lado do cliente e imprimi-lo.

Minha View está assim:

```
function GerarImagem()
    {
        var $conteudo = $("#canvas-container");
        html2canvas($conteudo[0], {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                EnviarImagem(base64)
            },
            logging: true
        });
    }

    function EnviarImagem(base64) {
        $.post('@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController")', { imagem: base64 })
            .done(function (data) {
                // Código para baixar o pdf (que ainda não sei como)
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("Error");
            });
    }
```

Meu Controller ficou da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(string imagem)
{
   try
   {
         MinhaImagem img = new MinhaImagem();

         string dataWithoutJpegMarker = imagem.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", String.Empty);
         img.Imagem = Convert.FromBase64String(dataWithoutJpegMarker);

         using (reports.MeuRelatorio relatorio = new reports.MeuRelatorio ())
         {
             relatorio.SetDataSource(img);
             PdfFormatOptions pfo = ExportOptions.CreatePdfFormatOptions();
             pfo.CreateBookmarksFromGroupTree = true;

             Stream stream = relatorio.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
             byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
             int byteCount = stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
             string fileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

             return Json(new
             {
                 success = false,
                 data = fileContent,
                 error = "Erro",
                 title = "Filtro"
              }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return Json(new
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = ex.Message,
                    error = "Erro",
                    title = "Filtro"
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

Obs: Em meu arquivo `.rpt` adicionei o campo `Imagem` na `sessão 5 (Rodapé)`.

Atualmente estou tendo uma **Exception** na seguinte linha:

```
relatorio.SetDataSource(img);
```

> "O objeto de origem de dados é inválido."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, descobri o problema. Tudo está perfeito! Exceto por uma coisa...
O método SetDataSource não aceita esse objeto, no meu caso usei uma `list` apesar de ser apenas uma imagem.

```
List<MinhaImagem> listImagem = new List<MinhaImagem>();
listImagem.Add(img);
```

Agora sim da pra usar o método SetDataSource:

```
relatorio.SetDataSource(listImagem);
```